# VBA code runs successfully only once

Tags: excel, caching, pivot-table, vba

I am trying to run the below code and it runs fine and does the job but only once. Then it starts throwing the run time error 1004: application or object defined error. *Context: I have about 15 pivot tables across 10 worksheets to be updated weekly. I change the source data every week and I want the pivot tables to be updated.*

```
Sub UpdateReports()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim PT As PivotTable, PTCache As PivotCache, newPT As PivotTable

Set wb = Application.Workbooks("Open items VIM Analytics September 16th, 2016.xlsx")
Set PTCache = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=wb.Worksheets("Vim open items 09.09.2016").Range("a:au"))
Set PT = wb.Worksheets("Per Location").PivotTables("PivotTable3")
Set newPT = wb.Worksheets("Per Location").PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PTCache, TableDestination:=wb.Worksheets("Per Location").Range("a200"))

PT.CacheIndex = newPT.CacheIndex

End Sub
```

I am getting the error on

```
Set newPT = wb.Worksheets("Per Location").PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PTCache, TableDestination:=wb.Worksheets("Per Location").Range("a200"))
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: I have updated my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this falls on the line

```
Set newPT = wb.Worksheets("Per Location").PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PTCache, TableDestination:=wb.Worksheets("Per Location").Range("a200"))
```

It can not create a pivot table because it already has the same name. I suggest to try to explicitly specify the name or remove before adding the old table.

You can still try to link the old table with the new cache.